# Hibernate. Configuration. Doesn't launch jar file

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jar

I package my project in jar by Maven. And when i launch a jar file, I got there are exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
    at util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    at util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at model.services.BusService.setBuses(BusService.java:30)
    at view.Runner.main(Runner.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"><hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carpark?useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">1111</property>

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping class="model.entities.Bus"/>
    <mapping class="model.entities.Driver"/>
    <mapping class="model.entities.Rote"/>
</session-factory>
```

My pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>view.Runner</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>hibernate.cfg.xml</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My HibernateUtil.java

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return (SessionFactory) new Exception(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    getSessionFactory().close();
}}
```

My BusService.java

```
package model.services;

import model.entities.Bus;
import model.repositories.BusRepository;
import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import util.HibernateUtil;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BusService {
private BusRepository busRepository;

public BusService() {
    busRepository = BusRepository.getInstance();
}

public BusRepository getBusRepository() {
    return busRepository;
}

public List<Bus> getBuses() {
    return busRepository.getBuses();
}

public void setBuses() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT ID, NUMBER , Rote_ID FROM bus").addEntity(Bus.class);
        List<Bus> buses = query.list();
        buses.size();
        busRepository.setBuses(buses);
    } finally {
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}

public List<Bus> findByNumber(Integer number) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    List<Bus> busesFinder = new ArrayList<Bus>();
    try {
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT ID, NUMBER , Rote_ID FROM bus");
        List<Bus> buses = query.list();
        for (Bus bus : buses) {
            if (bus.getNumber() == number)
                busesFinder.add(bus);
        }
        return busesFinder;
    } finally {
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}

public void save(Bus bus) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        session.save(bus);
    } finally {
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

}

30 row in BusService.java is (in method setBuses())

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
```

I used another hibernate version, but I got there are exceptions every time.
Now my hibernate version is 5.0.11.Final.

Please, help me solve the problem.
I need to launch jar file correct, without exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAR files generally do not include library dependencies (unlike WAR files), so you'll need to add them manually with a tool like maven-shade-plugin:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: It doesn't work. I add plugin like here https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html  
Can there be a problem in hibernate version?

Comment: What does `jar -tf NAME_OF_YOUR_SHADED_JAR` show? Are the Hibernate classes included?

Comment: Now i don't have there exceptions about org.hibernate.cfg (Thank you).  But maven create new xml file dependency-reduced-pom.xml. And when i compile my code, my application can't find hibernate.cfg.xml.  And when i lounch jar like 'jar -tf NAME_OF_YOUR_SHADED_JAR ', I get 'Error: Could not find or load main class jar' .

Comment: The command I showed (`jar -tf`) does not launch the application, it shows the contents of the archive, so if you get an error about not being able to locate a main file you're not using the right command.

Comment: Okey, sorry. Yes, this comand show libraries, and hibernate classes included. But I can't find org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.

Comment: That's peculiar, if the shade-plugin was properly configured it should be included, since it is part of the hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final jar (I just checked).

Comment: Can you show me your shade-plugin configure in pom.xml?

Comment: I haven't used it recently I'm afraid so I don't have a sample to show you

Comment: I have this pom.xml https://pastebin.com/qpcZ6kwJ . Can you say where i have a mistake (in maven-shade-plugin)?

Comment: The plugin configuration appears correct, actually, though you do have the dependency for Hibernate defined twice. When I do a `mvn clean package` the configuration file appears in the JAR file

Comment: That said, I just noticed you mentioned "could not find or load main class", which I missed earlier. This is easily solved: https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Make

Comment: I corrected my pom.xml (did dependcy for hibernate core once). And corrected problem with "could not find or load main class". And did 'mvn clean package'. And it doesn't work, too.

Comment: After package, maven create dependency-reduced-pom.xml. And when I launch a jar I get this problem https://pastebin.com/KZaiMMiX . In my opinion jar doesn't find a hibernate.cfg.xml , but in maven I pointed  locate of  hibernate.cfg.xml. And I didn't find org/hibernate/cfg (used command 'jar -tf')

Comment: That's well beyond the scope of your original question though, and there can be a number of causes. You should probably post a new question

Comment: Okey. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried few times clean maven and project, and after all work! Thanks a lot!